# Why does $f$ continuous and its Fourier coefficient converges absolutely implies the Fourier series converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I've read that if we have a continuous function defined on a circle and its Fourier coefficient converges absolutely, then that implies the Fourier series converges uniformly, but I'm not quite sure why because absolute convergence does not imply uniform convergence for infinite series. I think the reason is due to the Weierstrass $M$ test correct? If the Fourier series converges absolutely, then so do the Fourier coefficients which we use for the $M$ test. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. Since the complex exponentials are unimodular, Weierstrass M-test implies uniform convergence if the Fourier coefficients are absolutely summable.

Comment: It is a statement about trigonometric series. You do not need to know in advance that it is the Fourier series of a continuous function.